# Locking selected cells in row when A column of the row is Yes for all rows

Tags: excel, vba, range, locking, cell

I have a spreadsheet where column A asks a Yes/No question, I need the spreadsheet to lock cell columns C, D, E and J for that row. I need this action to be performed on every row.

So every row starts with the same Yes/No question then some cells are locked or left unlocked depending on the answer to Yes/No.

I have been working with some sample code I found online however it only works for a specific row and I am unsure how to make if apply to all rows. The sample code I found was:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Range("A*") = "Yes" Then
        Range("B1:B4").Locked = False
    ElseIf Range("A1") = "Refusing" Then
        Range("B1:B4").Locked = True
    End If
End Sub
```

What I would like to know if how to create a wildcard to apply this code to a range, and also how to have a range such as cells C*:E*, J* to be locked, I am not sure how to have both a range and another cell that is not in the same direct range included.

Comment: The `Target` parameter is the range that had been changed.  You should be testing that instead retrieving it from the worksheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code (untested). As @Comintern mentioned, `Target` is the range that has been changed.  Note, a range can be a single cell.  Using the `.Row` property returns the row of the changed cell.

`Cells` allows you to define the row and column as two separate values.  And `Range` can be used in conjunction with `Cells` to get a range of cells.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
On Error GoTo esub   'If an error occurs reprotect the sheet
Me.Unprotect   'Remove sheet protection to avoid runtime error

If Target.Column=1 and Target.Value="Yes" Then
    Range(Cells(Target.Row,"C"),Cells(Target.Row,"E")).Locked=False
    Cells(Target.Row,"J").Locked=False

ElseIf Target.Column=1 and Target.Value="Refusing" Then
    Range(Cells(Target.Row,"C"),Cells(Target.Row,"E")).Locked=True
    Cells(Target.Row,"J").Locked=True
End If

esub:
Me.Protect    'Reprotect sheet
End Sub
```

Comment: `Cells(Target.Row, "A")` is... odd.  You already have the range, so just use it:  `Target.EntireRow.Cells(1, 1)`.  Note that while "a range can be a single cell", in this case `Target` can be more than one cell, and anything in a change handler needs to account for that.

Comment: Cells(Target.Row, "A") is to ensure it only factors in the change in column A. In theory "Yes" could be written anywhere on the sheet which would trigger the changes in that row. This is an undesired effect.  I suppose I could have written `If Target.Column=1` but tomato to..mato?   And yes you're correct about Target potentially referring to more than one cell but the error handling is outside the scope of this question IMO. Feel free to write a more robust solution if you disagree

Comment: I wasn't referring to the method for getting column A from a given `Range` - I was commenting on retrieving it from the Worksheet instead of the `Target`.  The parameter is there to supply you with a `Range` - you shouldn't ever have to request a new one from the host worksheet with an unqualified `Range` or `Cells` call. Remember, this is one of the hottest code paths in Excel so efficiency matters.

Comment: Thank you this worked. Now I just have to deal with the 1004 error. I have tried `myWorksheet.Protect contents:=True, userinterfaceonly:=True` but I'm not 100% sure where to put it (Sorry very new to VBA).

Comment: @ Comintern.  Ah I see what you're saying now and that's a very good point.  I'll change the code to reflect that.

Comment: @JamesPritchard, it seems the runtime error is due to trying to run a macro on a protected sheet.  The only workaround I've found is to unprotect the sheet at the beginning of the macro, and reprotect it after. I've modified my a solution above to cover this.